# Is there a way to specify the number of lines in regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ for regex searches.

I often encounter with `.rtf` files, for example:

```
\\cellX US 123456 abcd

xxxx

xxxx

xxxx

xxxx

\\cellX US 78910 abcd
```

This is the regex I use:

```
\\\\cellX US [0-9]{1,}.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n]\\\\cellX US [0-9]{1,}.*
```

Is there any way to specify the number of lines in regex searches?
The number of lines is consistent.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are already using definite quantifiers and I believe that all the `[\r\n]` should actually be `[\r\n]+`, so use them?

```
\\\\cellX US [0-9]{1,}(?:.*[\r\n]+){4}\\\\cellX US [0-9]{1,}.*
```

Though you can also replace `{1,}` with `+` and `[0-9]` with `\d` usually:

```
\\\\cellX US \d+(?:.*[\r\n]+){4}\\\\cellX US \d+.*
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry. It did the Job For me and gave more information on regex. I Am actually new to RegEx but I want to explore the power of RegEx and with the help of people Like you sir, I Think I will grow. Thank You.

Comment: @RahulPatel Awesome. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted. That will give you 2 points and your question will also be marked as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
\\\\cellX US [0-9]{1,}([\s\S]*){5}\\\\cellX US [0-9]{1,}.*
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/45

Comment: Thank you VKS, for your Answer. I Am actually new to RegEx but because of your help I Think I will easily utilize the power of regEx